# I cannot work out this old code PHP osCommerce

Tags: php, oscommerce

I am working with an old system for a colleague that uses osCommerce and I am trying to change some information in the about us section. Does anyone know how you'd change the content? I am a little lost analysing this code. Where is the TEXT_INFORMATION coming from?

```
<?php
/*
  $Id$

  osCommerce, Open Source E-Commerce Solutions
  http://www.oscommerce.com

  Copyright (c) 2010 osCommerce

  Released under the GNU General Public License
*/

  require('includes/application_top.php');

  require(DIR_WS_LANGUAGES . $language . '/' . FILENAME_ABOUT_US);

  $breadcrumb->add(NAVBAR_TITLE, tep_href_link(FILENAME_ABOUT_US));

  require(DIR_WS_INCLUDES . 'template_top.php');
?>

<h1><?php echo HEADING_TITLE; ?></h1>

<div class="contentContainer">
  <div class="contentText">
    <?php echo TEXT_INFORMATION; ?>
  </div>
</div>

<?php
  require(DIR_WS_INCLUDES . 'template_bottom.php');
  require(DIR_WS_INCLUDES . 'application_bottom.php');
?>
```

Comment: check includes/application_top.php and template_top.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TEXT_INFORMATION` is definied in the language file. It has been required at the top on the line

```
require(DIR_WS_LANGUAGES . $language . '/' . FILENAME_ABOUT_US);
```

Assuming your language is english you can find the `about_us.php` with language in the folder

```
includes/languages/english
```

Comment: One other issue I have is I changed my password for my database, where do I access the Code to update this?

Comment: you can change this in `config.php` file, there are two of them, one for admin section and one for catalog section. You can find them in the folder `includes`

Comment: Omg thank you so so much, I really do appreciate your speedy response and help. You saved my backside there, kind regards